# Boost.LockFree Queue: How to get notified when queue is available for read or write?

Tags: c++, boost

Without busy polling the queue, is there a way to get notified, or callback, of when the queue becomes ready for read or write? Is there something similar to Linux nonblocking sockets, where after getting EWOULDBLOCK, I could select() on the socket to wait until it becomes ready.

Comment: I think wanting to do something like a `select` on your container is a good sign that a lock free queue is not the right data structure to be using. By definition, a lock free data structure can complete concurrent operations in a finite number of steps. If you introduce a select, the number of steps becomes potentially infinite, which ruins the point of the queue being lock free.

Comment: You want to lock on a lock-free container? Or, in other words, you want to wait for your your wait-free data structure?

Comment: I'm not looking for a locking mechanism, but a signalling mechanism. Say I have 2 threads A and B, and A sends data to B via lock free queue (A enqueue, B dequeue). If the queue is not full or empty, it works perfectly. But if the queue is empty, I would like to have a way for B to wait until there is something.